# Remove certain pattern of string from file name without affect extension

Tags: regex, powershell

I have file names like the following:

```
filename01_Sector_9009_part1.txt
filename02_Sector_1290_part2.series.txt
filename03_Sector_7916a_planning.csv
```

Now we just want to clean up and rename all files like this

```
filename01.txt
filename02.txt
filename03.csv
```

I wrote the following command

```
get-childitem *.*| foreach { rename-item $_ ($_.name -replace '(_Sector\s*)(\.[^.]*$|$)','')}
```

but it's not working.. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
-replace '_Sector.*(?=\.[^.]+$)'
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=_Sector.*%28%3F%3D%5C.%5B%5E.%5D%2B%24%29&i=filename01_Sector_9009_part1.txt%0D%0Afilename02_Sector_1290_part2.series.txt%0D%0Afilename03_Sector_7916a_planning.csv&r=&o=m).

Or,

```
-replace '_Sector.*(\.[^.]+$)', '$1'
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=_Sector.*%28%5C.%5B%5E.%5D%2B%24%29&i=filename01_Sector_9009_part1.txt%0D%0Afilename02_Sector_1290_part2.series.txt%0D%0Afilename03_Sector_7916a_planning.csv&r=%241&o=m).

**Pattern details**

- `_Sector` - literal text
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as many as possible
- `(?=\.[^.]+$)` - a location that is immediately followed with

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[^.]+`  - 1 or more chars other than a dot
  - `$` - end of string.

When a capturing group is used - `(\.[^.]+$)` - its value should be copied back to the string using a `$1` placeholder (also called a *replacement backreference*).

Answer (score 2):

Since [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7) parameter `-NewName` supports delay-script bind, you can pipe directly from your `Get-ChildItem` output. You can use the different parts of your `FileInfo` object to make the regex part simpler as well.

```
Get-ChildItem -File |
    Rename-Item -NewName {($_.BaseName -replace '_Sector.*') + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

Just remove the `-WhatIf` parameter if you are happy with the proposed rename operation.

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) has the `-File` parameter, which returns only files. So filtering on `*.*` is not necessary starting with PowerShell v3+.

Answer (score 0):

This would replace everything from the underscore to a literal period with null, using positive lookahead for the period so it doesn't get removed.

```
get-childitem | 
  rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '_.*(?=\.)' } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item:       C:\users\js\foo\filename01_Sector_9009_part1.txt 
Destination: C:\users\js\foo\filename01.txt".

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item:        C:\users\js\foo\filename02_Sector_1290_part2.series.txt
 Destination: C:\users\js\foo\filename02.txt".

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item:       C:\users\js\foo\filename03_Sector_7916a_planning.csv 
Destination: C:\users\js\foo\filename03.csv".
```